# Is Newton's third law wrong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity

It is said that if we do action on any body then that body gives equal and opposite reaction, but in the case of two balls in which one is kept static at a place and we throw another one ball towards that static ball then we find that the static ball is moving but the second ball is not also moving in the opposite direction it still moves in the same direction with a small velocity so what is the reason?

Comment: I've deleted some comments and would remind potential responders that comments are not to be used for answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

Velocities and forces are not the same thing.  When the balls collide, the static ball does indeed apply an equal and opposite force to the ball that is moving forward.  However that force is not high enough (or over a long enough duration) to apply enough of a negative acceleration to stop the ball that was originally moving.

As you learn more, you'll learn about the laws of conservation of momentum and conservation of energy.  These will help you predict how much each ball moves.